# Flight cancelled because of COVID19, and they are offering a voucher instead of a full refund. Is that legal?

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, covid-19

Airline is Tap Air Portugal. My flight departs from the US to Lisbon. Is there something I can do?

Comment: I suggest following these SE posts - https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/155243/air-france-cancellation-policy-seems-to-violate-eu261 and https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/50127/does-air-france-cancellation-policy-violate-eu-261-2004

Comment: Short answer: no, it's not legal. What can you do: that's the billion dollar question, I'm afraid :-(

Comment: They are pushing for a voucher because they're worried about their own cash flow and/or they are contemplating bankruptcy; in bankruptcy your voucher will be void and they keep your cash.